# dplyr Subsetting rows by groups with multiple thresholds

Tags: r, dplyr, grouping, slice

I am currently trying to answer a fairly straightforward question: List the top 20% of pharmacies (measured by units) within each region.

I first measured the amount of products sold per pharmacy, sorted it DESC and have the following thresholds for 20%:

Here's how I calculated the numbers:

```
spad_number <- c_spad_results %>%
  group_by(province)%>%
  summarise(tot_pharma = n())
View(spad_number)

spad_number_20_threshold <- spad_number %>%
  mutate(Top_20_threshold = round(tot_pharma*0.20))%>%
  dplyr::select(Top_20_threshold,province)
```

Giving me this result dataframe

A tibble: 4 × 2
Top_20_threshold province
 
1              248 Berlin
2               38 Genua
3               27 London
4               42 Turin

And now I'd like to get one dataframe where I get only the top 20% and couldn't come up with a better solution than this:

```
top_20_pharma <- ranked_pharmas %>%
  group_by(province) %>%
  slice(1:spad_number_20_threshold$Top_20_threshold)
View(top_20_pharma)
```

And get the issue that I keep getting

Warning messages:
1: In 1:spad_number_20_threshold$Top_20_threshold :
numerical expression has 4 elements: only the first used
2: In 1:spad_number_20_threshold$Top_20_threshold :
numerical expression has 4 elements: only the first used
3: In 1:spad_number_20_threshold$Top_20_threshold :
numerical expression has 4 elements: only the first used
4: In 1:spad_number_20_threshold$Top_20_threshold :
numerical expression has 4 elements: only the first used

How do I make sure that my ranked_pharmas dataframe rows are selected according to each region correctly, instead of just reading the first value for the dataframe.

Thank you so much in advance for any kind of help!!!

Best :)

I was expecting to get 248 Berlin, 38 Genua, 27 London and 42 pharmacies but get over the double.
I have experimented with the filter function

```
#filter(row_number(desc(total_units)) <= first(spad_number_20_threshold$Top_20_threshold))
```

but it also just reads the first value of 248 and gives 248 pharmacies per group.Something like a Vlookup from excel is missing here, but I'm not experienced with R enough :/

Comment: Hi Olaf! Welcome to StackOverflow. Please edit your question to include the output of dput(head(c_spad_results)) . Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about the structure of c_spad_results, yet I believe `slice_head` may solve your problem if the dataset is arranged.

```
c_spad_results |>
  group_by(province) |>
  slice_head(prop = 0.2)
```